# My graphics card is overheating and I'm trying to determine the most effective solutions

Tags: graphics-card, fan, cooling, nvidia-geforce, overheating

**My hardware profile:**

> **Case:** [APEX PC-389-C Black Steel ATX Mid Tower Computer Case](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811154095)
>  
>   **Mobo:** [Gigabyte GA-MA785G-UD3H](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128395)
>  
>   **PSU:** [Antec Neo Eco 400W](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817371029)
>  
>   **CPU:** [AMD Athlon II X4 640](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103871)
>  
>   **RAM:** [5GB Dual-Channel DDR2](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231166) (I later bought an extra 1GB stick of this)
>   **GPU:** [1024MB GeForce GTX 550TI](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125410) (and [pics](http://www.ebay.com/itm/GIGABYTE-NVIDIA-GeForce-GTX-550-Ti-1GB-GDDR5-VGA-DVI-HDMI-PCI-Express-Video-Card-/200828677531) with accurate cooling fan)
>   **VID:** [E390-A1 Vizio 39" LED TV, 1920x1080 resolution](http://store.vizio.com/e390a1.html)
>  
>   **HDD:** [WD 320GB SATA - WD3200AAKS](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136074)
>   **HDD:** [SG 2TB SATA - ST2000DL004](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822148681R&Tpk=ST2000DL004)
>   **DVD:** LiteOn iHAS222 DVD R/W SATA
>   **OS:** Windows 7 (x64) and Ubuntu 13.04 (x64)

---

**My situation:**

I'm a college student, 20, who's just moved to the city and I'm on a tight budget.

I used to have an nVidia GeForce 8800 GTX that died on me, but I've upgraded to a 550TI. The problem is, it overheats. On almost every game I play. This was verified last night when I couldn't play Dear Esther.

I also had an older, much smaller monitor that I used to use before I upgraded to this much larger TV. Now, the increased resolution forces my graphics card to control too many pixels and it burns out at about twice the rate that it used to.

I've gotten wise lately and done benchmarks and tests. I've downloaded and used FurMark to push the card to its limits and determined the problem is definitely heat. I run the 1920x1080 Burn-In Test and within 3 minutes, the card's heat steadily rises from a default 35-60'C depending on my activity, to a harmful 90'C whereupon the screen flashes black, the drivers crash, etc. The exact same symptoms as when the card breaks down as I play games.

I'm looking for a more effective heating solution than what I have. I have four fans-- One on the back, one on the CPU, one on the GPU (dual-fan), and one on the side panel. None of this appears sufficient.

---

**What I've tried:**

- Removing the side panel to increase air flow has barely a measurable effect on the card's temps.
- Using [Precision X](https://www.evga.com/precision/) to manually force the fans to run 100% to see if it makes a difference by stress-testing in FurMark ("15-minute burn-in test"), but it only climbs to critical temperatures at a *slightly* lower rate.
- I've re-applied Arctic Silver to the card between the GPU and Heatsink.
- I've kept the fans clean.

None of this matters, the card is simply not getting cooled rapidly enough.

---

**Thoughts**

If you take a look at my specs, you'll notice that I have a ATX Mini-Tower case and a certain Gigabyte motherboard. If you take a look at the [motherboard photos](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128395), you may notice the PCIe slots on the board. If you take the overhead image of the board and rotate it 90' Clock-wise, you will see how the board sits inside the case. The video card rests fans-down from the PCIe slots (it takes the space of both of them).

I believe this is the culprit of the overheating. The graphics card, when installed, rests near the bottom. The gap between the fans and the bottom is only about 1"-2". It never occurred to me before, but now I'm wondering if this isn't one big (if not the biggest) culprit in why the fans can't cool the GPU in time.

If anyone has any suggestions, please help. I've looked briefly into liquid cooling, which I think would more than adequately solve my problem, except the apparatus is either expensive or nonexistent for my GPU.

---

**Also,**

I don't like the cooling fans on the card. They're loud. If anyone knows of good GPU-cooling fans or an otherwise cost-effect method of GPU cooling that might work better or quieter, I'd really love to hear it.

Thanks for the help,
DarkIron112

**NOTE:** I've edited the post to include product links that make references much easier.

Comment: Sounds like you should either replace the graphic cards with say a low profile card or migrate to a larger case. The current fans are loud only because they are unable to cool the card because of air flow.

Comment: First the obvious question: How hot it the air which leads to the fans which cool the GPU? I assume that you checked that you are not feeding the cooling with the hot-air from a CPU fan or hot air from a PSU. Still, it would be nice to have that confirmed. :)  Secondly: I looked at the motherboard picture and I do not grok the "PCIe slots near the EDGE". I see PCI slots near the edge and two brightly coloured PCI-e slots.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm considering getting a bigger case as my prime method of solving this problem-- but if I drop the money and it doesn't _absolutely_ work, I'm done for a few months, financially. I just want to be sure. Also, would you be willing to post your response as an answer, perhaps with some case suggestions? I don't mean to ask you to do my shopping for me, just merely to point out considerations when buying cases (with real-world examples?) that would steer me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you smoke in the room with your computer?

Comment: @Hennes Inside my case, the GPU is the lowest component, nested beside hard drives and directly below my RAM and CPU. Heat rises, but maybe in that box the card is getting hot air shot at it anyway. If this were a significant factor, however, wouldn't opening the side-panel of the case have helped me more measurably? Second, I was unclear in the orientation of the board-- I'll amend my post, please re-read that section for an eleboration.

Comment: @kobalts Absolutely no smoke, and I spray it for dust every few months.

Comment: @DarkIron112 - I cannot make product recomendations. You are going to need to do measurements of your current case and purchase something larger then it. While after market GPU fans could help its not a guarantee. Have you tried to not use the sides of your case?  Might help to know what case you have currently.

Comment: Another sanity check: Which way are the fans blowing? Is one pushing cool air into the case and is one sucking hot air out of the case? Optionally make a diagram [like this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lFp88.jpg) for yourself.

Comment: @Ramhound, I've updated the post to include product links. Now you can see that I have, apparently, a Mid tower when I mistakenly wrote Mini on it before.

Comment: @Hennes, I've updated my post with product links. Now you can see a picture of my video card (the ebay link) with the cooling apparatus as it exists in my computer. Try visualizing this card fans-down near the bottom of my computer case. I'm not sure of the air-flow at present.

Comment: @DarkIron112 - You don't happen to have a box fan handy do you?  If not and you have Amazon Prime here is one for $15.99 + tax http://www.amazon.com/Comfort-Zone-CZ10B-10-Inch-3-Speed/dp/B000OEOWP6/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1380814929&sr=8-3&keywords=box+fans otherwise just add another $10 and you can get free shipping.  You have an intesting problem.

Comment: @Ramhound If you're implying that I put this box fan up against the case to pull the air, I may be willing to do that in an emergency but this is not at all a suitable solution long-term, considering the existing fans' noise already bothers me. However, you just gave me the idea to use the box-fan to test the effects, so thank you.

Comment: @DarkIron112 - I am just wondering if blowing a bunch of cooler air might help.  If it does then that proves its an airflow problem (otherwise it won't have a major effect) of course just blowing moderate cool air might not be enough if the air is being heated beyond a certain point.

Comment: @Ramhound this is a good point. While my apartment is likely to become cool in the winter (landlord controls the heat), it is hard to know whether the air will be cool enough. Do you think I should orient the box-fan to push cool air in, or pull warm air out?

Comment: @DarkIron112 - I assume you have the fan, so were talking about only time and not money, so try both :-)

Comment: @Ramhound Alright, why not. I think there is a box fan down in the main room of my building, I bet I can bum that off of the landlord for a little bit while I run my tests. I'll get back to here eventually with the results.

Comment: *that might work better or quieter, I'd really love to hear it.* Hah... I see what you did there! (However, you *don't* want to hear it)

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin Thanks for the comment! Reminded me to post the results of this.

**Final Results**
--

I ended up finding out the card had a warranty in effect still. I sent it to Gigabyte and they repaired it. It's come back without any currently known issues.

Thanks for the hard work everyone! Sorry I couldnt' give a true cause of the issue.

Comment: @jwarner You *did* give a true cause of the issue... it was a defective card. BTW, feel free to post this as an answer so a mod can delete some of these comments...

Comment: I think you should take this as a sign you should spend less time playing games and more time focusing on your college work ;)

Comment: @Majenko With this videocard being down I haven't played PC games in a year or two... even then, I only get to play on weekends after I'm done with *everything* else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The solution has finally arrived, everyone!

The card itself was faulty. I found it to be under warranty and had it RMA'd to Gigabyte, where it was returned to me and now works. No visible change on the card, either.